# Why inner element's style doesn't apply in tailwind?

Tags: html, css, web, tailwind-css

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="head.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-10">
        <div class="col-start-1 col-end-3 bg-slate-600 h-screen"></div>
        <div class="col-span-8">
            <div class="p-4 bg-slate-400 m-4 h-screen">
                <div class="bg-yellow-100 m-4 ">Hello</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>

</body>
```

I Need to add header in gray section but effect doesn't apply there! Yellow background doesn't appear, only text is shown[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtdyH.png)
It works fine if in include

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

but not with

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="head.css">
```

(using tailwind CLI)

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://play.tailwindcss.com/lcznGKSuIC). Please add all relevant details as well.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't include Tailwind into your project. The code above works as expected. You just need to add `<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>` inside `<head>`.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-10">
    <div class="col-start-1 col-end-3 bg-slate-600 h-screen"></div>
    <div class="col-span-8">
      <div class="p-4 bg-slate-400 m-4 h-screen">
        <div class="bg-yellow-100 m-4 ">Hello</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```